# Apache POI reading Excel data and putting them in a HashSet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel sheet called guitars.xlsx

```
| Guitar Name | Guitar Year | Guitar Maker |

| Les Paul | 1979 | Gibson |

| 800ce | 2013 | Taylor |

| Stratocaster | 1966 | Fender |
```

How would I use Apache POI to read this file and return these values in a HashSet?

Comment: I was following these directions: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/  Although I can read the file, since I am new to Java, I wasn't sure how put those data into a HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Sheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

String name;
for(int line=1; ; line++) {
    Row row = worksheet.getRow(line);
    Cell cell0 = row.getCell(0), cell1 = row.getCell(1), cell2 = row.getCell(2);
    String name, year, maker;

    if(cell0==null||(name=cell0.getStringCellValue())==null) break;
    year = cell1!=null? cell1.getStringCellValue():null;
    maker = cell2!=null? cell2.getStringCellValue():null;

    Record r = new Record(name, year, maker);
    set.add(r);
}
```

Don't forget to define hashCode() based on all the fields and equals() functions for Record to use it in HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

You should search on your own for tutorials such as [this one](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/). Here is a pretty simple (untested) example though:

```
File excelFile = new File("guitars.xlsx");
Workbook excelWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Set<String> data = new HashSet<String>();

for(Iterator<Row> rowIterator = excelWorkBook.getSheetAt(0).iterator(); rowIterator.hasNext();) {
    for(Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = rowIterator.next().cellIterator(); cellIterator.hasNext();) {
        data.add(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```